# Is it possible to use Windows integrated auth without IIS?

Tags: node.js, authentication, iis, nginx

I have an nginx reverse proxy to a few node apps. Our users are all on a Windows domain controlled network. I'm aware I can use [express-ntlm](https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm) or [passport-windowsauth](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth) to prompt the user for their login credentials, but that's non-integrated auth.

Is it possible to use integrated auth (windows authenticated users can bypass credentials prompt) directly from within node.js (or nginx) without IIS (or Apache)? If so, how?

I suppose we could replace nginx with IIS as the reverse proxy, but I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: Yes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi Never used it and very few seem to use it so feel free to give a feedback if it works for you.

Comment: Excellent! Just tested and confirmed it works... Now only if it would also work on a non-windows environment (server still on windows network) :)

Comment: It's possible but you'll need to dev a node module yourself or use Apache: https://fuhm.net/linux-and-active-directory/

Comment: @ShanShan Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @ShanShan probably you should post an answer to summarize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, there is a package called [node-sspi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi). It only works on Windows environment though.

> #### Windows SSPI server-side authentication for Node
>
> NodeSSPI to Node.js is what mod-auth-sspi to Apache HTTPD. In a nutshell NodeSSPI authenticates incoming HTTP(S) requests through native Windows SSPI, hence NodeSSPI runs on Windows only.

If you need to use it for other OS, you need to develop your own node module or [use Apache](https://fuhm.net/linux-and-active-directory/).